# Как поправить картинки?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Как сделать чтобы картинки не обрезались, когда высота блока меньше, чем высота самой картинки? Нужно сделать чтобы они просто уменьшались по высоте. Как можно реализовать с помощью flexbox или без?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.slider__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  width: 7680px;
}

.wrapper__slide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper__button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 8%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: 0.1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper__button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}

.slider__button_perv {
  left: 0;
}

.slider__button_next {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper__slide">
      <img src="http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874100_1383101_25792ac067.jpg" alt="Слайд 1">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper__slide">
      <img src="http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874104_1822794_cefef52967.jpg" alt="Слайд 2">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper__slide">
      <img src="http://storage2.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874108_2174295_2a76b9d678.jpg" alt="Слайд 3">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper__slide">
      <img src="http://storage4.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874123_9925860_740e80c1e2.jpg" alt="Слайд 4">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper__slider-position">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper__button slider__button_perv js-slider__button_perv"></div>
  <div class="wrapper__button slider__button_next js-slider__button_next"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Уменьшались только по высоте(сплющивались) или пропорционально?

Comment: @E_K, хотелось бы что бы качество особо не терялось, т.е. что бы шло как фон что-ли

Comment: картинка не может не потерять в качестве если будет на всю ширину и при этом иметь не полную высоту.

Comment: @E_K, я понимаю, я имею ввиду, чтобы как фон картинка стояла, если это возможно

Comment: Сделайте картинку через background для `wrapper__item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Решение

Нужно было поработать с самой картинкой и блоком в котором она располагается:

```
.wrapper__slide {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.wrapper__slide img {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

Кое что еще удалил, например: `width: 7680px`.

### Пример

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.slider__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper__slide {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.wrapper__slide img {
  max-height: 500px;
}

.wrapper__button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 8%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: 0.1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper__button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}

.slider__button_perv {
  left: 0;
}

.slider__button_next {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider__wrapper">
      <div class="wrapper__slide">
        <img src="http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874100_1383101_25792ac067.jpg" alt="Слайд 1">
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper__slide">
        <img src="http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874104_1822794_cefef52967.jpg" alt="Слайд 2">
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper__slide">
        <img src="http://storage2.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874108_2174295_2a76b9d678.jpg" alt="Слайд 3">
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper__slide">
        <img src="http://storage4.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874123_9925860_740e80c1e2.jpg" alt="Слайд 4">
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper__slider-position">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper__button slider__button_perv js-slider__button_perv"></div>
    <div class="wrapper__button slider__button_next js-slider__button_next"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

ps. Думаю замыкание картинок на `javascript` сам сможешь сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Прописать картинке внутри блока стиль `object-fit: scale-down;`. Всё.